# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure saving state: active fragment was removed from the FragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments, androidx

I recently changed my app to target API Level 28 and also started using androidx instead of support libraries. After the change, I'm noticing a crash that has the following traceback

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure saving state: active MyFragment{22caf6fc (04a7bbf5-8806-4a45-a25d-616ed244bf18) id=0x7f1000ff} was removed from the FragmentManager
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveAllState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2301)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.saveAllState(FragmentController.java:150)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onSaveInstanceState(FragmentActivity.java:496)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onSaveInstanceState(AppCompatActivity.java:510)
       at com.company.utils.MyAppCompatActivity.onSaveInstanceState(MyAppCompatActivity.java:161)
       at android.app.Activity.performSaveInstanceState(Activity.java:1311)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnSaveInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1288)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.callCallActivityOnSaveInstanceState(ActivityThread.java:4166)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3577)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3633)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1491)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5541)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
```

All my activities are extending from a base activity `MyAppCompatActivity` which extends from `AppCompatActivity`. And in the `onSaveInstanceState` method of `MyAppCompatActivity`, I have a few log lines there. I have three fragments in this activity implemented under a ViewPager with `FragmentStatePageAdapter` and the activity itself is not overriding `onSaveInstanceState` method.

I went through a few SO posts close to this such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34480430/failure-saving-state-active-supportmapfragment-has-cleared-index-1) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20984658/failure-saving-activity-state-which-extends-another-activity), but it looks as if it's happening when we're using `FragmentManager`'s methods to manage the fragments ourselves rather than using a ViewPagerAdapter handle it. I'm not doing that and the closest thing that I'm doing away from the usual flow is overriding `FragmentStatePageAdapter`'s methods `instantiateItem` and `destroyItem` to help me have a method to get a fragment's reference in the code as given in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15261142/1929309).

Comment: Try adding the fragments using the `commitAllowingStateLoss()` method instead on the normal `commit()`.

Comment: I'm not using the `commit()` method in my code since it is handled by the `FragmentStatePageAdapter` itself, which, I link to my `ViewPager`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Which Fragment library version did you use? There is [an issue with 1.1.0-alpha01](https://issuetracker.google.com/119256498).

Comment: Yes, we're using `androidx.core:core:1.1.0-alpha01`. Is there any workaround? I couldn't figure out later releases for this!

Comment: Thanks! As specified in the issuetracker, I've set the fragment dependency version to 1.0.0 and the error seems to be resolved. I've accepted the answer.

Comment: Note that the issue tracker was updated to state that alpha02 fixes this issue. Upgrading to androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0-alpha02 should fix this.

Comment: ^ I take this back. I tried alpha02 and it's still crashing for me.

Comment: Crash not occurring after updating to 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0-alpha03'

Comment: It started to happen to me when I upgrade `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0-alpha02` to **2.2.0-alpha04**, so reverted back to **2.2.0-alpha02** and it's working fine.

Comment: getting the same issue with '2.2.0-alpha02' too

Comment: same issue with `androidx.core:core:1.3.0-alpha01`

Comment: same issue with `implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'` and this is latest version today ( 08 Aug. 2020 )

Answer (score 5):

I am using the latest gradle as below

> implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.1.0-alpha03'

I have compared crashing fragment with other fragment code and found the difference as below: 
Crashing fragment has method **setRetainInstance(true);** inside onCreateView() as shown in below snippet.

```
     @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       setRetainInstance(true);
}
```

I come across the link which says not to use **setRetainInstance** : [setRetainInstance - This can only be used with fragments not in the back stack](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#setRetainInstance%28kotlin.Boolean%29)

I removed the setRetainInstance(true) for crashing fragmnet; It's working now.

**How to replicate this issue:**
MainActivity --> HomeFragment --> FirstFragment(crashing fragment) --> HomeFragment

MainActivity loads with HomeFragment which replaced by FirstFragment and then going back to HomeFragment.
Then moving my app to background and crash happens with below exception.

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failure saving state: active 
FirstFragment{fd50037 (4a8b618e-a0a8-45d0-aa37-ba08393b8f68)
 id=0x7f08009c} was removed from the FragmentManager
```

Comment: I have the same issue after using Android Studio to move to ActiveX

Answer (score 1):

Add a dependency in build.gradle app

```
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0-alpha05'
```

it will works for me, thanks to

> Refer this - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119256498

my issues are in run time I'm giving permission to camera and storage after that seconds the camera is open my app is crashed. I use this my issue is solved

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have any setRetainInstance(true); 
When i was going through my code i saw there was another transaction which i was doing using fragment manager in onResume for the same fragment .

Answer (score 0):

This issue is sometime caused by a double click on a button which finishes the current activity.

add :

```
button.setEnable="false";
```

for all buttons in your view ;)

enjoy